# AVPlayer setRate property create glitchy if we use setRate frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, avfoundation

I have used AVPlayer to play videos in slow motion. I am using addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval: message to get time at specific interval, and checking some condition according to current playback time. once condition is fulfilled, I am calculating rate and using setRate: message of AVPlayer. i.e I am setting rate frequently. but once I have done with this, video is not playing smoothly, it's glitchy.
Can anybody please let me know how can I set setRate: frequently.
Thanks

Comment: what values do you pass to setRate:? it only accepts values in steps of (if I remember correctly) 0.25.

Comment: How often are you setting the rate? What is your time interval for observing time? Please post code.

Comment: I am setting values like 0.88, 0.71, 0.5, 0.47, 0.33, 0.21 and again same values in increasing order.

Comment: and I have to set rate values like every 0.1 second.

Comment: Actually, setRate is reflecting for me but the problem, which I am facing is when I set rate, it have a jerk, if I set the rate two times like at 5:10 and 5:25, it will jerk at these two times.

Comment: @RajuPanwar I am trying to achieve a similar thing. The issue is iPhone 6 now records 240 fps video. How would I know which rate is absolute for my recorded video?

Answer (score 0):

We were having kind of the same issue.  We were using setRate:1 (or 1.5/2.0 depending on what the user chose) to play the video instead of calling play.  We have changed to call play then setRate: and the video plays smoothly now.

Comment: I have to set Rate property like 10 times in a second or event more.

Comment: This seemed to help but after looking at move videos we still see a slight jerk like you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, is there any solution for this problem please.